# Bolete (?) mushroom identification

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I'm attempting to identify a gorgeous set of mushrooms.  I'm not anything resembling a mycologist, and I have *no* intention on consuming these... But for my own curiosity, I'm trying to identify these striking mushrooms.

Some notes:

- These mushrooms were found directly under a red oak tree, in central New Hampshire, near Lake Winnipesaukee
- The mushrooms were found this morning, on August 2nd
- The largest cap was about 6 inches in diameter
- The pore surface bruised rapidly (10s of seconds) to a blackish blue, even when lightly bruised.  Harder pressure bruised nearly instantly.
- The cap flesh, though, did not.  You can see a slightly more-yellow streak where I rubbed the cap pretty hard.  Even after several minutes, no bruising appeared.
- The stipe similarly did not bruise.  In fact, it was quite solid.
- When cut in half, no bruising was apparent, even after several minutes (when the picture was taken)

Digging around, I thought maybe it was *B. Bicolor*, but the cracked appearance of the cap doesn't match basically any photos I can find.  It's not as bruisable as *B. sensibilus*.

Can anyone help me identify this?  I can run further tests as well.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: For even more precision, make a spore print overnight and photograph.